# No re-render when the state changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I need cool red seconds cells in red.
But i got blue, what have I done wrong?

I have a function, that check prevent cell, and mark cell.

AI_CELL = RED color 
HIGHLIGHT_CELL = BLUE color 
USER_CELL = GREEN color

```
const checkWinnerScore = () => {
    let [y, x] = prevCell;

    let copyCells = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cells));

    if (copyCells[y][x] === HIGHLIGHT_CELL) {
      
      // I assign value, but cell do not coolerd in red.
      copyCells[y][x] = AI_CELL;
      setCells(copyCells);
      setAiScore(aiScore + 1);
      
    } else if (copyCells[y][x] === AI_CELL) {
      return;
    }
  };
```

Full example in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-gates-zfcmm?file=/src/components/Cells.js:2098-2430